# Adhoc Created on XCode 4 installs fine on iPad but not on iPhone. What could be wrong?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ad-hoc-distribution

Here's what I have already tried:

1. I created adhoc with and without entitlement.plist. But this adhoc installs fine on iPad but not on iPhone.

It gives "Code signing error".

What else should I check?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

are you sure the phone is listed on the provisioning profile?